# Oracle - Question about removing single quotes in Where-in clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have no idea about it.
We insert the queries we want into our in-house enterprise database so that user can download the reports they want with parameters.

Query Example

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE name = ?
```

USER put parameter 'abc' when they download report, Then system will replace question mark to parameter user put like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE name = 'abc'
```

But If I want to make where clause like below and user input id list 123,456,789, system will make like below.

```
WHERE ID in ('123,456,789')
```

In this case, How can I make like below? ID should not be string, So I need to remove single quotes.

```
WHERE ID in (123,456,789)
```

Please give me any idea. (I only can change query, not backend, frontend server)

Comment: I think the backend logic must be changed to accommodate numbers

Comment: looks like the quotes are being inserted by your reporting software, not Oracle. Oracle uses double quotes to identify case-sensitive object labels; it uses *single* quotes to identify string values.

Comment: How can we know what **your** software is doing with this data? It should identify by itself what is list and what is not and generate (single) quotes accordingly.

Comment: The backend should not replace values, the bind variables should be passed through to the SQL engine to be parsed. It especially should not replace the values and the surround them in double quotes as that is for an identifier; if anything it should be using single quotes which are for literals.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to split the string, use `LIKE` and include the delimiters (so you match an entire term rather than a partial match):

```sql
WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || id || ',%'
```

Comment: It is working for me. More simpler then mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

resolved with below

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('?', '[^,]+', 1, level) AS parts
FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('?', '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
```